# React native TCP guide issue. "Object prototype may only be an Object or null." when doing var net = require('net');

Tags: react-native, tcpsocket

I am following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tcp) guide on using tcp sockets in react native. I followed all the steps but when I run I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O369s.png).

The problem is with this line:

```
    var net = require('net');
```

This is my package.json

```
{
 "name": "MyTCP",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
 "test": "jest",
 "postinstall": "rn-nodeify --install stream,process,util --hack"
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "process": "^0.11.0",
 "react": "15.4.2",
 "react-native": "0.41.1",
 "react-native-tcp": "^3.2.0",
 "readable-stream": "^1.0.33",
 "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
 "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
  "jest": "18.1.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2",
  "rn-nodeify": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
 "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "react-native": {
 "net": "react-native-tcp",
 "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
 "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
 "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
 "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
 "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
 "stream": "stream-browserify"
 },
"browser": {
 "net": "react-native-tcp",
 "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
 "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
 "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
 "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
 "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
 "stream": "stream-browserify"
}
}
```

I'm running on Windows 10 on an android device.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?